# How to use the null conditional operator on a C# dynamic ExpandoObject property chain

Tags: c#, json.net

I am working with a JSON object with a few different possible structures and want to elegantly extract a value from a few possible paths.

e.g. my dynamic object has a name under one of these paths

1. `PayloadResult > response > personEntity > name > givenName`
2. `PayloadResult > response > businessEntity > mainName > organisationName`
3. `PayloadResult > response > businessEntity > tradingName > formattedName`

Is there an elegant way to extract the name? The null conditional operator but be perfect:

```
var name = dynamic.PayloadResult.response.personEntity?.name?.givenName ?? 
           dynamic.PayloadResult.response?.businessEntity?.mainName?.organisationName ??
           dynamic.PayloadResult.response?.businessEntity.tradingName.formattedName
```

However it still throws a `RuntimeBinderException`

There are many other answers around detecting if a property exists, but I need to know if the *entire property chain* exists, not just one level.

Comment: I would avoid dynamic

Comment: Are you able to explain why @DanielA.White?

Comment: Because dynamic means no guarantee of correct names. It confuses your API user if not documented clearly, it also will confuse future developers including you, when you need to debug the json response. Compiler also can't catch typos for you (be it accidents or someone later refactored the field names), meaning you only know something is wrong during runtime. I recommend define the classes instead, make properties optional if needed.

Answer (score 3):

As you are tagging the JSON.NET, you should consider extracting the property with `JObject` and null-conditional operator (`?.`).

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

JObject jObj = JObject.Parse(json);

string givenName = jObj["PayloadResult"]?["response"]?["personEntity"]?["name"]?["givenName"]?
    .ToString();

string organisationName = jObj["PayloadResult"]?["response"]?["businessEntity"]?["mainName"]?["organisationName"]?
    .ToString();

string formattedName = jObj["PayloadResult"]?["response"]?["businessEntity"]?["tradingName"]?["formattedName"]?
    .ToString();
```

Or you may provide the JSON path. It returns `null` if the JSON path is invalid.

```cs
string givenName = jObj.SelectToken("PayloadResult.response.personEntity.name.givenName")?
    .ToString();

string organisationName = jObj.SelectToken("PayloadResult.response.businessEntity.mainName.organisationName")?
    .ToString();

string formattedName = jObj.SelectToken("PayloadResult.response.businessEntity.tradingName.formattedName")?
    .ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

If your properties are `ExpandoObject` as well, you can use a recursive method to extract the names up until the last level of the chain.

```
    public static void GetCurrentNames(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, List<string> fullyQualifiedPaths, string fullyQualifiedPath = "")
    {
        if (fullyQualifiedPaths is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(fullyQualifiedPaths));
        }

        foreach (var entry in dictionary)
        {
            var childKey = entry.Key;
            fullyQualifiedPath += childKey;

            if (entry.Value is IDictionary<string, object> childValue)
            {
                fullyQualifiedPath += ".";

                GetCurrentNames(childValue, fullyQualifiedPaths, fullyQualifiedPath);
                continue;
            }

            fullyQualifiedPaths.Add(fullyQualifiedPath);

            break;
        }
    }
```

When calling the method above, first cast your ExpandoObject to `IDictionary<string, object>` and provide also an empty `List<string>`:

```
var rootObject = new ExpandoObject();
var fullyQualifiedPaths = new List<string>();

// Add properties and nested dynamic properties
[...]

GetCurrentNames(rootObject, fullyQualifiedPaths);
// fullyQualifiedPaths now contains all the absolute paths.
```

The following sample Console Application demonstrates how to do it:

```
using ExtensionMethods;
using System.Dynamic;

namespace Stackoverflow_77575154
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var rootObject = new ExpandoObject();

            var payloadResult = rootObject
                .AddMember("PayloadResult");

            var response = payloadResult
                .AddMember("response");

            response
                .AddMember("personEntity")
                .AddMember("name")
                .AddMember("givenName", "Eliah");

            var businessEntity = response
                 .AddMember("businessEntity");

            businessEntity
                .AddMember("mainName")
                .AddMember("organisationName", "Nintendo");
        
            businessEntity
                .AddMember("tradingName")
                .AddMember("formattedName", "任天堂");

            var fullyQualifiedPaths = new List<string>();

            GetCurrentNames(rootObject, fullyQualifiedPaths);

            foreach (var path in fullyQualifiedPaths)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(path);
            }
        }

        public static void GetCurrentNames(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, List<string> fullyQualifiedPaths, string fullyQualifiedPath = "")
        {
            if (fullyQualifiedPaths is null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(fullyQualifiedPaths));
            }

            foreach (var entry in dictionary)
            {
                var childKey = entry.Key;
                fullyQualifiedPath += childKey;

                if (entry.Value is IDictionary<string, object> childValue)
                {
                    fullyQualifiedPath += ".";

                    GetCurrentNames(childValue, fullyQualifiedPaths, fullyQualifiedPath);
                    continue;
                }

                fullyQualifiedPaths.Add(fullyQualifiedPath);

                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

namespace ExtensionMethods
{
    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static ExpandoObject AddMember(this ExpandoObject expando, string propertyName, object value = null)
        {
            var dictionary = expando as IDictionary<string, object>;

            if (value is null)
            {
                var child = new ExpandoObject();
                dictionary.Add(propertyName, child);
                return child;
            }

            dictionary.Add(propertyName, value);
            return expando;
        }
    }
}
```